# Extension of SPARQL syntax

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am trying to extend SPARQL by introducing new clauses in the syntax. Is there a way to do this using graphdb?
I need a headstart for this

Comment: Can you elaborate on _why_ you want to do this? Because unless this is a research project on your part, it seems unlikely that extending the parser is the best way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, its a project and extending the parser would be the only option. Can you tell if the plugins can be used to transform the parsed query into algebra model that the underlying store can understand?

Comment: Bit hard to say without knowing more about what _kind_ of extension you have in mind.

Comment: I want to introduce a statement like select, ask, describe say, XYZ ?a where ( ?a lives ?b . ?b born 1999 ). The underlying logic of computing the XYZ statement will be different from any known staement like SELECT or ASK

Comment: You can add custom functions, magic predicates, and special FROM graphs with plugins. I very much doubt you need to change the basic form of query. SELECT returns a table and CONSTRUCT returns a graph, what do you need XYZ to return?

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB uses the [Eclipse RDF4J](https://rdf4j.org/) SPARQL parser, which is open-source, so you can extend that easily enough. The parser is defined as a [JavaCC](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/) grammar file (see [sparql.jjt in rdf4j github](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/blob/master/core/queryparser/sparql/src/main/java/org/eclipse/rdf4j/query/parser/sparql/ast/sparql.jjt)), so the easiest way to exend is to add your extensions to that grammar file and then recompile the parser using JavaCC.

However, given that, once you've parsed something, you need to transform it into an algebra model that then the underlying triplestore can actually *do* something with, extending the parser is the easy part.